# Why return is giving me the statement and None

Tags: python

When I run the below code:

```
def heart_value(name1,name2,name3):
    if name1 == "Rachel":
        return print("So you are Rachel!")
    elif name2 == "Rachel":
        print("Ah, so the second person is Rachel.")
        return print('Right?')
    elif name1 != 'Rachel':
        return print('So Rachel is not the first person.')
    else:
        return print('ok')

print(heart_value("Rachel","Rachel","Mike"))
```

It gives me as follows:

> ```
> So you are Rachel!
> None
> ```

Why does it also print `None`?

Comment: Because you are printing the output of another `print` function. You can avoid that by just returning the string, not the `print` function.

Comment: `print` prints something to the screen as a `side effect.` The return-value of `print(<anything>)` is always `None`, because the print function does not return a value like the `sum` function does for example

Comment: I don't know who voted this question down but just my two cents, it does not deserve to be voted down (hence my offsetting vote-up). In general I think if you vote-down a new user you should probably offer an explanation of why. It's not particularly helpful for a new user to get vote-downs with no elaboration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `print` function does not return a value. You need to just return the string `return '<string>'`, not `return print('<string>')`.

The reason it is printing 'None' is because you are calling `print()` on the value the function returns (which is `None`) so that value therefore appears in the console.

i.e.

```
if name1 == "Rachel":
    return "So you are Rachel!"
elif name2 == "Rachel":
    return "Ah, so the second person is Rachel. \n Right?"
elif name1 != 'Rachel':
    return 'So Rachel is not the first person.'
else:
    return 'ok'

print(heart_value("Rachel","Rachel","Mike"))
```

Comment: Well, it returns `None`, as the OP demonstrates, but that's not the desired return value.

Comment: @chepner the OP is asking why it returns None, not how to fix it to return a desired value

Comment: The fact the they are trying to print the return value suggests they expect it to return the printed message.

Comment: Thanks so much! Solved problem!

Answer (score 0):

The `print()` function performs an action (printing to the console), but doesn't return anything.

So when you use the statement `return(print("ok"))`, the return function calls the print("ok") function, which prints the text "ok" in the console, but doesn't return anything to the `return()` function, which means a value of None is passed back to the function that originally called `heart_value()`.

What you need to do is `return()` the string object itself ("ok"). That way, when you `print()` the function `heart_value()`, the `print()` statement will evaluate the function, get a string object, and print that.